# A script executed by MOUNT

Tags: bash, mount, cifs

I write a script in BASH that performs MOUNT for a particular folder
The MOUNT command requires a UID & GID I want the script to take from etc / passwd /
The details and each will be written to his own variable and then in the MOUNT command
I will summon the variables
The script:

```
#Var 
Username='user'
Password='password'
Uid=''
Gid=''

$ mount -t cifs -o username=$Username,password=$Password,uid=$Uid,gid=$Gid,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.120/storage /mnt/storage
```

Comment: Sounds fine. What's your question about this?

Comment: How is the script supposed to know while line (account) in `/etc/passw` it should work? Other than that, like at the command `getent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that I understood correctly that your question is about the variable assignments.
Here's a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

Username=${1}
Password=${2}
Uid=`cat /etc/passwd | grep ${Username} | cut -d: -f3`
Gid=`cat /etc/passwd | grep ${Username} | cut -d: -f4`


mount -t cifs -o username="${Username}",password="${Password}",uid=${Uid},gid=${Gid},rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.120/storage /mnt/storage
```

Note that:

- Username and password are provided as the first and second parameter to the script.
- Uid and Gid are read from /etc/passwd
- I've put double quotes around your password to accomodate for passwords with spaces